# Jquery Validate to check selectbox unqiue and required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have used the jquery validate plugin to check select box unique and required.

However, **check unique is not working at all** and **check required is only work for the first select box** ,

how to fix this ? Thank you

jquery

```
        $("#insertResult").validate({
    rules: {
         'select[]': {
              required: true,
              unique: true
          }
       },
   });
```

html

```
<form id="insertResult" method="post" action="excelSQL.php" >
       <select id="selectField0" name="select[]" style="float:left">
                       <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
    </select>


    <select id="selectField1" name="select[]" style="float:left">
    <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Updated:
I have edited the js file which i have done before and i have tried selectField0 or selectField_0 , still no luck

```
    checkForm: function() {
        this.prepareForm();
        for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
            if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
                for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                    this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
                }
                } else {
            this.check( elements[i] );
        }
        }
    return this.valid();
```

},

Comment: Where is the HTML element that has the id="insertResult"?

Comment: it is an form id , i have put it in my question, sorry for omitting this

Comment: According to this post, you must modify the validator plug-in itself: http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/27/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements/

Comment: @jmort253, thanks, i have edited the plugin before so this may not be the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with the jQuery validator. There are two ways around this problem:

**Method1:**

Modify the jQuery Validator plug-in so that it handles both by following these instructions: http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/27/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements/

**Method2:**

Apply the Validator to each select individually:

HTML:

```
<form id="insertResult" method="post" action="excelSQL.php" >
    <select id="selectField0" name="select[]" style="float:left" class="error">
        <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selectField1" name="select[]" style="float:left">
        <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
    </select>
    ...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("#insertResult").find("select").each(function() {
     $(this).validate({
         rules: {
             'select[]': {
                 required: true,
                 unique: true
              }
         }
     });
 });
```

**Method #3:**

While jQuery plugins can be quite valuable for the more basic tasks, in some cases, what you're trying to do may in fact be outside the scope of what the plug-in was designed to do. Whenever I hear solutions like "modify the library code", it makes me think that perhaps that library is just not for me. This depends on the complexity of the modifications, and the likelihood that my coworkers or successors may have trouble figuring out why things stopped working when they updated the plugin to the latest version.

Thus, method #3 sidesteps the jQuery validator altogether and only uses jQuery to facilitate the basic validation:

JavaScript:

```
    // submit handler for form
    $('#insertResult').submit(function(event) { 

        // if either field is not selected, show error and don't submit
        if( itemNotSelected( $('#selectField0'), $('#selectField1') ) == true )  { 

            $('.error2').css("display","block");
            event.preventDefault(); 
            return false;

        } else if( isEqual($("#selectField0"), $("#selectField1") ) == true ) {

            $('.error2').css("display","none");
            $('.error1').css("display","block");alert("afda")
            event.preventDefault(); 
            return false;

        } 
    });

    // hide error text on focus of element
    $('#selectField0, #selectField1').focus(function() {
        $('.error2, .error1').hide();

    });

// helper methods to check if both fields are equal
function isEqual(elem1, elem2) {
    return (elem1.find("option:selected").html() == 
            elem2.find("option:selected").html());
}

// helper methods to check if one field (or both) is not selected
function itemNotSelected(elem1, elem2) {
    return ( elem1.find("option:selected").html() == "Select one" || 
             elem2.find("option:selected").html() == "Select one" );
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selectField0" name="select[]" style="float:left" class="error">
    <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
</select>

<select id="selectField1" name="select[]" style="float:left">
    <option selected="" value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="1_Name2">1_Name2</option>
</select>
<span class="error2" style="display:none">These are required fields</span>
<span class="error1" style="display:none">Fields must be unique</span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

The above code will submit the form if and only if the following conditions are true:

- Both select boxes have items selected. This meets the "required" condition.
- The selections are not the same and meets the "unique" condition.
- When a user focuses the select box, the errors disappear.
- If the user tries to submit without the above submit conditions being true, the following errors are shown:
- If one or more select box is not selected, the "These are required fields" message shows.
- If both are equal and selected, the "Fields must be unique" message shows.

Comment: They don't have the same name the select[] makes each part of a select array when passed to PHP

Comment: @ehudokai - Hmmm. Ok. Thanks. Removing this answer.

Comment: Thanks jmort253, and as point out by ehudokai, what i would like to have is an select[]={ 1_Name2, email ....etc}

Comment: Thanks, since I have tried #1 method before and it not works.  I perfer #2 method, however, it just skip the vaildation? Is there any error in #2 method?

Comment: Also. i notice that the generated html is <select id="selectField0" name="select[]" style="float:left" novalidate="novalidate">
</select> Are there any hints?

Comment: I am looking into this further to see if I can find anything useful. I haven't forgotten you :)

Comment: update: I'm looking through examples here http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ and looking for anything that would lead to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is quite weird as i have follow the tutorial but it still not working , should be some parsing problem? As it can only validate the first select box

Comment: How tied to jQuery validator are you? I'm going to post an alternative answer that will work for this specific scenario. I think it's only marginally better than modifying the plug-in, but it does work.

Comment: Sorry just back from lunch ,The problem is the number of select box is not fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your last comment. Did you see method #3?  for clarity, method #3 doesn't use the validator plugin.

Comment: There is selectbox3 , selectbox4 ..and so on

Comment: I thought there were only 2. :(  You could read the value from each select, in a for loop, put the value in an array, and on each element compare against all of the elements in the array to look for  matches. If you find one, break out of the loop. If you get to the end without a match, then they're all unique. You could modify the isEqual function so that it takes a CSS selector for all of the select boxes, then loops through, pushes the data into an array, and compares them.